# K8S use pod affinty to work on multi nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, kubernetes

I’ve used the current config for pod anti affinity like following
The app have 3 replicas and we have 3 nodes,
When I use the “hard” config for affinity `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` I see that the pods was scheduled on 3 diff nodes which is what we need.

**1 pod in 1 node**

The problem is that wen I use the **soft** like the following
 `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`

```
 spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchLabels:
                    app: myapp
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              weight: 100
```

I see that **2 pods** on 1 node , one pod in other node, and **one node without any pod.**

Any idea how I can achieve with the soft definition that each pod will be in different node ?

btw, I try to deploy it over and over again and got the same results

**I  want to make sure that I've at least one replica on each node at any give time**

Comment: It sounds like what you're looking for is a DaemonSet.

Comment: @DanielMann - why would you think its better ? which pros it have that pods with affinty doesnt have?

Comment: @DanielMann - could you please answer my question?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/ - daemonset guarantees one replica per node, even if you add/remove nodes

Comment: what if he only needs 3 replicas and scales to 100 nodes?

Comment: @4c74356b41 - do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: "preferred" means preferred and not mandatory. If the scheduler has reason not to follow your request it will do so. To be sure, use "required".

Comment: @Henry - thanks, but the problem that if I have 3 pods in 3 node how the upgrade will take a place ?